# Using "as much as" in a sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, causative-get

Is this sentence correct:
"It is not the words that angered me as much as the way you used them".

I want to mean that I got angry more because of the way you used the words than the words themselves.

Actually while asking it I came across one more problem.
 "Do I need to use get with angry? or is angry a verb?" For example:

I angered or I got angry.
Which one of the above is correct?

Earlier I used to use the latter one (get angry) but once I came across a news published in hindustan times (an Indian daily) in which the former one(angered) was used. I cannot provide a link to the news since the news is a couple of day old and  I don't have the edition.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct.  Another variation on it would be to say "so much as" instead of "as much as."

To anger is a transitive verb and needs an object.  The sentence:

> I angered. ❌

is therefore incorrect.  You don't anger; you anger *someone*.  Your original sentence uses the verb "anger" correctly: "the words" is the subject, and "me" is the object.  (A subtle point: "I angered her" and "I made her angry" are both correct, but the latter sounds more natural.)

"Angry" is an adjective.  You can be angry, get angry, or become angry.  "I got angry" is therefore correct.